# How to handle the extra newline character in stdin

Tags: c, scanf

Consider the following program :

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

char c;
printf("Want to continue? :");
scanf("%c",&c);
while(c=='y')
  {
      printf("Want to continue? :");
      scanf("%c",&c);
  }
return 0;
}
```

What was wanted here is that the program continues till the user keeps on entering the character `y`.
But it exits after the first iteration even if the user enter `y`. As per my understanding, this is
 happening because when I type `y` I also enter a new line and so the next time scanf will fetch this
 newline character instead of the character that I typed.
One way to avoid this is simply use `getchar()` after each scanf so it simply eats up the new line
 character. Is there any better alternative to it?

Comment: Use `scanf(" %c",&c);` inside `while`

Comment: Some explanation: most of the format specifiers for `scanf` automatically filter leading whitespace, but `%c` and `%[]` and `%n` do not. Adding a space in front of the `%` instructs `scanf` to filter leading whitespace here too.

Comment: You could also ignore everything except `'y'` or `'n'`: `do scanf("%c", &c); while (c != 'y' && c != 'n');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a space **before** the character to read.

```
scanf(" %c",&c);
```

Putting it **after** can cause troubles: [What is the effect of trailing white space in a scanf() format string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19499060/what-is-the-effect-of-trailing-white-space-in-a-scanf-format-string))

EDIT: to answer your question about why it works. Well because that's just the way `scanf` has been built. In this page http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/ you can read:

**Whitespace character**: the function will read and ignore any whitespace characters encountered before the next non-whitespace character (whitespace characters include spaces, newline and tab characters -- see isspace). **A single whitespace in the format string validates any quantity of whitespace characters extracted from the stream (including none).**

Comment: Thanks that works. But I don't understand the difference between scanf("%c ",&c) and what you have mentioned. Although this does not work. What is the reason for it?

Comment: @nidhi I made an edit to answer this question